# Docker: Error starting container: Unable to load the AUFS module

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, vagrant, docker

After `ssh`ing into my ec2 instance using `vagrant` on `ubuntu`, I tried running

`sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu echo 'hello'`, but I get this error:

`Error starting container da3124903fc4: Unable to load the AUFS module`

How can I load this `AUFS module`?

I already have `aufs-tools` installed.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, distribution, and kernel are you running?  `cat /etc/lsb-release ; uname -r` will tell you.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04, 3.8.0-19-generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran `apt-get purge lxc-docker` and reinstalled it with the following command:

`curl https://get.docker.io | sudo sh`

I got the following error, but the installation continued and finished.

```
Ensuring basic dependencies are installed...
Looking in /proc/filesystems to see if we have AUFS support...
Ahem, it looks like the current kernel does not support AUFS.
Let's see if we can load the AUFS module with modprobe...
FATAL: Module aufs not found.
Ahem, things didn't turn out as expected.
```

When I run `docker run ubuntu echo hello` the result is `hello`, so it looks like everything is alright.

Comment: I've added the HTTPS URL @XavierShay!

Answer (score 6):

This has helped me in installing aufs, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lxc wget bsdtar curl
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
sudo modprobe aufs
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Installing extras is now obsolete, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/153023/what-is-the-linux-image-extra-package-for-and-do-i-need-it

Answer (score 3):

For those stumbling across this in 2021 and beyond, like myself while debugging docker-ce 20.* issues, this blurb from the docker documentation may help:

> When possible, overlay2 is the recommended storage driver. When installing Docker for the first time, overlay2 is used by default. Previously, aufs was used by default when available, but this is no longer the case. If you want to use aufs on new installations going forward, you need to explicitly configure it, and you may need to install extra packages, such as linux-image-extra. See aufs.

source: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#docker-engine---community

Answer (score 0):

Actual solution that helped solving it on my Debian 10 Box

```bash
apt-get install aufs-dkms
modprobe aufs
dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: `apt-get install aufs-dkms` returns an long list of linux images and then `You should explicitly select one to install. E: Package 'aufs-dkms' has no installation candidate`